# EF Code First not initializing database

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an EF Code First DbContext, a custom initializer which seeds data, and a bootstrap static class which sets the initializer in the Application_Start part of Global.asax.

The initializer looks like:

```
public class DropCreateDatabaseWithSeedData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyEntities context)
    {
        context.Genders.Add(new Gender { Id = 1, Name = "Male", SortOrder = 1 });
        context.Genders.Add(new Gender { Id = 2, Name = "Female", SortOrder = 2 });
        context.Genders.Add(new Gender { Id = 3, Name = "Prefer not to say", SortOrder = 3 });
    }
}
```

The bootstrap static class looks like:

```
public static class Bootstrap
{
    public static void InitialiseDataAccessLayer()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWithSeedData());
        var uow = new UnitOfWork();
        uow.Context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
    }
}
```

The Global.asax Application_Start looks like:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());

        DataAccess.Infrastructure.Bootstrap.InitialiseDataAccessLayer();
    }
```

All looks as it should, however no database initialisation is happening - if I run the application without a preexisting database at all, I get an SqlClient exception:

```
A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "Cannot open database MyEntities requested by the login.  The login failed.  Login failed for user 'localdev'."
```

The user localdev has full access to the SQL Server, and I can log into that SQL Server with SSMS and create, drop, update etc databases fine.

If I run the application with an existing but empty database, the application tries to run the first query it can (in this case, some user verification queries) and fails on an "Invalid Object" exception as it tries to query tables that don't exist.

If I run uow.Context.Database.Create() with no existing database, the database is indeed created but no seed data is inserted.

If I change the initializer to DropCreateDatabaseAlways, no initilization happens.

Breakpoints are being hit at all of the above lines of code, so nothing immediate is being skipped - the only breakpoint which isn't hit is the seed method in the initializer, so thats not even being called (which isn't surprising if initialization isnt happening!).

At this point, I'm out of ideas - everything is set up as it looks like it should be, but no database initialisation is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moo,

Even though the call to `InitialiseDataAccessLayer()` looks correct with what looks like a correct call to `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWithSeedData());` try a direct call to `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWithSeedData());` from the `ApplicationStart`.

It will not instantiate your `UnitOfWork`, but I am not sure that you need to do that at this time since you are seeding.

If nothing else, its another idea.