# EF 6 Database initializer not called

Tags: entity-framework

I'm unable to get the datbase initializer called. I've tried with both the build in and created a deribed on. I've got this code:

```
       //Database.SetInitializer(new KjokkenSeedInitializer()); -- not working 
       Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<KjokkenContext>()); // - not working

       var context = new KjokkenContext();
       context.Database.Initialize(true);

       var x = context.Persons.ToList();
```

Any idea what might be wrong? I've seen some other similar questions ( [EF Code First not initializing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774645/ef-code-first-not-initializing-database) ) but I'm not getting any initializer to run.

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: what do you mean by "not called", what do you get when you reach line var x=context.Persons.ToList()

Comment: Just mye old list of persons